# What causes swirling in bokeh?

Tags: lens-design, bokeh

The East German antique lens, Zeiss Biotar 75mm, is famous for producing a swirling, water-like bokeh as illustrated in the photo below:

[image]

What optical materials and/or design cause this effect, which appears to be a coma aberration? Is it characteristic of any double Gauss design or is there something unique about the Biotar that creates it?

Comment: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65143/what-swirly-bokeh-technique-is-this-and-how-can-i-achieve-it/65306#65306

Comment: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52126/what-is-the-cause-of-this-non-uniform-bokeh-effect